# Manually applying rotations and translations to Matrix4 in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I am trying to understand the co-ordinate spaces of three.js, I understand that there is object.matrix and object.matrixWorld.

After stumbling upon this blog post [Matrix Basics. How to step away from storing an orientation as ’3 angles’](http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/), I decided to try to learn how to manipulate properties of the Matrix4 manually thus avoiding using Euler rotations.

All I am trying to do is translate my cube away from the origin 0,0,0 then rotate it in world space. The result in my mind would be that the cube translates on y axis first, then the rotate would bring it in a large arc back to the plane, but what actually happens is it just goes back to the origin ignoring the translation.

I have been doing a lot of reading about vectors and matrices and I'm confident I understand the theory behind them enough now. What I don't really get is how three.js handles the matrixWorld and matrix. I've attempted both!

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/151/

Just look in the render() function to see what I'm trying to do!

**EDIT - [solved] UPDATED JS FIDDLE OF WORKING VERSION 14/09/12**

With the help of the answer below, I thought I would post my updated fiddle demonstrating what I wanted to achieve - http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/363/

Comment: Just as an aside, probably won't help you much here as I've only briefly looked at Three.js, but if you are looking at 3D rotations, you really should get some understanding of Quaternions, as well as Vectors and Matrices.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal - yes that is on the list as three.js implements Quats. I think I will learn to walk before I run :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/phenomnomnominal/SCXNQ/152/), which is what I think you want.

EDIT:
Oops, got the Matrix order wrong (another thing that you need to have a solid grasp of) -> try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/phenomnomnominal/SCXNQ/153/) aswell.

Comment: I read about the order of applying things to matrices, thanks for pointing that out, also what is the point of the make functions, eg: makeTranslation instead of using translate?

Comment: I had a quick look at the source and it seems that makeTranslation physically changes the `Matrix` to whatever you give it, whereas translate performs the translation operation on the existing `Matrix`. I can't think of any particular reasons why you would completely overwrite a `Matrix` object rather than making a new one, possibly there is some value as a memory optimisation?

Comment: I see, well thanks for your help I'm now getting the results I expect from most of the matrix operations.

Comment: Glad to help - I've been spending the last few weeks getting my head around this stuff myself!

Comment: Its better to attach a version of threejs where it is working. I am using latest version r71 and it says the functions are removed