# ThreeJS: Updating existing objects with Matrix4

Tags: three.js

Can anyone offer suitable documentation for updating ThreeJS objects with Matrix4?  I've found very few samples online, and they seem to use outdated syntax.  In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118126/manually-applying-rotations-and-translations-to-matrix4-in-three-js) for example, the multiplySelf syntax is deprecated and the jsfiddle doesn't work.

I've had success getting the transformation to work during the init() function:

```
object.matrixAutoUpdate=false;
scene.add( object );
var m=new THREE.Matrix4(1,0,0,0,0,1.132,0,0,0,0,1.3,0,0,0,0,1);                 
object.applyMatrix(m);
```

But I'm specifically trying to activate a transition based on Matrix4 (a user clicks a button and the transformation happens as an animation).  I'm having a lot of trouble getting the transformation to operate after the scene is loaded, so thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
object.matrix.set(1,0,0,0,0,1.132,0,0,0,0,1.3,0,0,0,0,1);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Doob.  This works for setting a matrix once, but when I try to update the matrix of the same object (by selecting a button in the browser), I don't get any transformation.  Is there another syntax for updating the matrix of an object?

Comment: You probably need to set `object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` to `true`.

Comment: This seems to no longer work.  At least it partially works.  I get an updated rotation but not position.